# Calculate age based on Birthdate

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will give me results for people turning 65 within 3 months based on date of birth. Any help would be appreciated!

In the WHERE clause I'm using the following which shows me results for people that are 64, but I'm not sure how to get the last 3 months

```
    FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, DOB, GETDATE()) / 365.25) = 64
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is very product specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datediff can have some odd effects, and I find myself avoiding it. This is how I'd approach it (on SQL Server / T-SQL).

```
SELECT
    p.*
FROM
    Person p
WHERE
    dateadd(yy, 65, p.dob)) between getdate() and dateadd(mm,3,getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEADD()` function coupled with `DATEDIFF()` like

```
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, DOB, DATEADD(month, 3, GETDATE())) / 365.25) >= 65
```

Comment: This will return everyone who has already turned 65, I believe ... plus I always have misgivings about using 365.25. It's good enough for most purposes, but not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

I think it's much easier to maintain rather than having a lot of nested functions.

**Update: (*this should be accurate enough - precission up to days*)**

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOB, GETDATE()) BETWEEN (64 * 12) AND (65 * 12 - 3)
AND DOB >= CAST(CAST(YEAR   (DATEADD(MONTH, -3, dob)) as nvarchar(8)) + 
                CAST(MONTH  (DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())) as nvarchar(8)) +
                CAST(DAY    (DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())) as nvarchar(8)) as datetime);
```

The first condition checks to see if the person's age is 64 and higher up to 65 years minus 3 months (but will include people older than 3 months but less than 4 months).

The second condition is the one which increases the accuracy of the query to return people who are only up to exactly 3 months.

Example:

```
declare @tbl table (dob datetime);
insert @tbl values ('19530101')
    , ('19530201')
    , ('19521231')
    , ('19521201')
    , ('19520101');

select *
from @tbl
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOB, GETDATE()) BETWEEN (64 * 12) AND (65 * 12 - 3)
    AND DOB >= CAST(CAST(YEAR (DATEADD(MONTH, -3, dob)) as nvarchar(8)) + 
               CAST(MONTH     (DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())) as nvarchar(8)) +
               CAST(DAY       (DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())) as nvarchar(8)) as datetime);
```

Comment: getting difference in days will be more accurate than difference in months.

Comment: @vkp You're right, it would be more accurate but then the calculation of days "between" would have to take into consideration leap days.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use BEETWEEN

`where DATEDIFF(DAY, DOB, GETDATE()) / 365.25 between 64 and 64.4`

Comment: Why "between 64 and 64.4"? Wouldn't "between 64.75 and 65" be closer to the mark?

Comment: oh eah, I'm tired a little bit for today